# Boxes in tikzposter

Tags: boxes, tikzposter

I designed a poster with the style `tikzsposter`.
My problems are the too big distances between title of the poster and a box and the position of the text in a box
I tried already the options given in `tikzposter`, but nothing has worked... Is it possible to change that distances?

[image: Bild hochladen]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a2paper, portrait, margin=0mm, innermargin=10mm,     titleinnersep=0mm,blockbodyinnersep=0mm,     blocktitleinnersep=0mm, blockverticalspace=5mm, colspace=5mm, subcolspace=5mm]{tikzposter}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}  

\usetitlestyle{Envelope}
\usebackgroundstyle{Rays}
\useblockstyle{Envelope}
\usecolorstyle{Spain}

\title{Titel}
\author{Autor}
 \institute{Institut}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{columns}
\column{0.33}

\block{}
{\small
\section*{Aufgabenstellung}
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT    TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT 
 } 
 \end{columns}
 \end{document}
```

Can anyone please help me now with my problem?

Comment: Can you please post your code?  See: [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)

Comment: The intention is that a block title should be placed in the first argument to `\block`, i.e. `\block{Aufgabenstellung}{Text}`.

Comment: Crosspost info, already discussed at [goLaTeX.de](http://golatex.de/poster-in-latex-t15876.html) and [LaTeX-Community.org](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=26623), one may see there for development.

Answer (score 2):

As I already answered to the crosspost at [LaTeX-Community.org](http://latex-community.org/forum/), you can set the lengths `titletoblockverticalspace` and `bodyinnersep` as options:

```
\maketitle[titletoblockverticalspace=10pt]
...
\block[bodyinnersep=10pt]{}
...
```

[image: output]

Full forum discussion is at: [Boxes in tikzposter](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=26623).